# T-SQL query is hanging

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

First off, I didn't write this query. It's created dynamically in code I inherited. It works 99.9999% of the time so I'd prefer not to touch it. However. The following query just hangs:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            Track
            , RequestID
            , ClientName
            , MatterName
            , CASE
                  WHEN PATINDEX('% - Yellow', PhaseName) > 0 THEN REPLACE(PhaseName, ' - Yellow', '')
                  ELSE PhaseName
              END                 AS PhaseName
            , MPApprovalStatusName
            , DateOpened
            , RequestorName
            , Notes
            , IsNewClient
            , AffiliatedClients
        FROM
            (
                SELECT TOP 15
                    *
                FROM
                    vwRequests AS T1
                WHERE
                    ClientName LIKE '%harch%'
                ORDER BY
                    DateOpened DESC
            ) AS T2
        ORDER BY
            DateOpened ASC
    ) AS T3
ORDER BY
    DateOpened DESC
```

If I replace "harch" in the LIKE statement with "chameleon" (both should return results), results are returned with no problem. If I change the LIKE '%harch%' to = '(complete client name)', it works. If I leave LIKE, but remove the CASE statement and just output the PhaseName, it works. I experimented and did this:

```
SELECT TOP 15
    *
    , PATINDEX('% - Yellow', PhaseName)
FROM
    vwRequests AS T1
WHERE
    ClientName LIKE '%harch%'
ORDER BY
    DateOpened DESC
```

It works fine. However, when I do this:

```
SELECT TOP 15
    *
    , PATINDEX('% - Yellow', PhaseName)
    , REPLACE(PhaseName, ' - Yellow', '')
FROM
    vwRequests AS T1
WHERE
    ClientName LIKE '%harch%'
ORDER BY
    DateOpened DESC
```

it hangs. What's weird about this is that PhaseName in this case is "Completed." Why would the REPLACE statement cause a problem? And why would LIKE be problematic in this case but not others? I'm on SQL Server 2017. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest to enable `live execution plan` on ssms and monitor to see where in the plan it stuck

Comment: Can you post the full DDL of the table including indexes, and share the plan via [pastetheplan](https://www.pastetheplan.com)

Comment: @Melanie It looks like you are having underlying hidden query in your vwRequests. You can provide it in addition to live execution plan for better understanding.

Comment: @Charlieface - I'm new to execution plans. How can I copy it to paste it into Brent's tool? I don't see a copy option in SSMS.

Comment: Right click on the plan there is an option to copy XML

Comment: OK, beautiful. But now when I try to post the XML in a code block, only the first line shows up.